# How to output hostnames into Test-TestSuite.xml with Ant while using Junit test suite to run multiple classes from different machines

Tags: java, ant, junit

I am using Ant 1.7 + Junit 4 + Selenium Grid 2 for my functional testing.

In Junit 4, I use "@RunWith (Suite.class)" to run multiple classes. 
The code is here:

```
package com.black;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({TestGrid.class,TestGrid2.class})
public class TestAll{
}
```

You can see, this TestAll.java calls two classes - TestGrid.class and TestGrid2.class.

TestGrid.class run on one Windows 7 (10.1.3.50), and TestGrid2.class runs on another Windows 7 machine (10.1.3.77).

code is here:

------------TestGrid.class-------------

```
package com.blackline;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class TestGrid {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    int sleepTime = 0;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("TestGrid.java setUp.");
        //Use Firefox
        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://10.1.3.50:5555/wd/hub"), capability);


        baseUrl = "http://10.1.3.12/";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Capabilities actualCapabilities = ((RemoteWebDriver)driver).getCapabilities(); 
        System.out.println(actualCapabilities); 
    }

    @Test
    public void test01()
    {
        System.out.println(1);
    }
    @Test
    public void test02()
    {
        System.out.println(2);
        assertEquals("a", "b");
    }


  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
  }

}
```

----------TestGrid2.java-------------

```
package com.xbosoft.blackline;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class TestGrid2 {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    int sleepTime = 0;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("TestGrid2.java setUp.");
        //Use Firefox
        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://10.1.3.77:5555/wd/hub"), capability);


        baseUrl = "http://10.1.3.12/";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Capabilities actualCapabilities = ((RemoteWebDriver)driver).getCapabilities(); 
        System.out.println(actualCapabilities); 
    }

     @Test(timeout=10000)
    public void testSelenium() throws InterruptedException
    {
        driver.get("http://seleniumhq.org/");
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        driver.get("http://seleniumhq.org/projects/");
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        driver.get("http://seleniumhq.org/download/");
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        driver.get("http://seleniumhq.org/docs/");
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        driver.get("http://seleniumhq.org/support/");
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        driver.get("http://seleniumhq.org/");
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        driver.get("http://seleniumhq.org/projects/");
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }
}
```

The junit and junitReport parts in Ant build.xml are as the following

===================

```
<target name="junit" depends="compile">
    <junit printsummary="yes" fork="true" haltonfailure="false" failureproperty="tests.failed" showoutput="true">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement path="${classes.dir}" />
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
                <include name="*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
        <formatter type="xml" />
        <batchtest todir="${report.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${classes.dir}">
                <include name="**/TestAll.class" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>

<target name="executeRemote">
    <sshexec host="10.1.3.50"
        username="sshuser"
        password="qqqqq"
        trust="true"
        command="D:\bat.bat"/>
</target>

<target name="junitReport" depends="junit">

    <junitreport todir="report">
        <fileset dir="report">
            <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
        </fileset>
        <report styledir="reportstyle" format="frames" todir="report" />
    </junitreport>
    <fail if="tests.failed" />

</target>
```

==========================

In the exported HTML report, for the Hostname field, it is always displayed as the machine's name where the TestAll.java located. But it cannot get the names of the machines where the scripts are actually ran.

I can't post image. It is here.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6ZL4.png

I have checked the Ant exported TESTS-TestSuites.xml.
In this file, it doesn't have the hostnames of the remote machines.

Is there a way to output the remote machines' host names into this TESTS-TestSuites.xml file, then I can use XSLT to display them into HTML report?

I guess I have to change Ant's source code somewhere?

Thanks!